# Are nested breakpoints possible in pdb--if not, what prevents them?

Tags: python, breakpoints, pdb

Following a [tutorial on Python's debugger](https://pymotw.com/2/pdb/), I used `pdb.set_trace()` to interrupt the sample code.  It worked, but what if you are at the interactive prompt and want another nested breakpoint?

```
(Pdb) def test(): pdb.set_trace(); print "don't print this yet"
(Pdb) test()
don't print this yet
```

It didn't stop.  Is the debugger fundamentally "one deep"?  e.g. is this is a limitation of Python's hooks, or just something pdb doesn't choose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this is a limitation of Python's hooks, or just something pdb doesn't choose to do?

It appears to be a limitation of the hooks.

I did a test to see what was being called and what wasn't (putting print statements in `/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py`)

Quick inspection finds `set_trace` in [pdb.py](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/pdb.py#L1210):

```
def set_trace():
    Pdb().set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)
```

That calls set_trace in [bdb.py](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/bdb.py#L184)

```
def set_trace(self, frame=None):
    """Start debugging from `frame`.
    If frame is not specified, debugging starts from caller's frame.
    """
    if frame is None:
        frame = sys._getframe().f_back
    self.reset()
    while frame:
        frame.f_trace = self.trace_dispatch
        self.botframe = frame
        frame = frame.f_back
    self.set_step()
    sys.settrace(self.trace_dispatch)
```

This sets up a callback to trace_dispatch, [also in bdb.py](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/bdb.py#L42).  The sys.settrace code itself is perhaps in [threading.py](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Lib/threading.py#L88):

```
def settrace(func):
    global _trace_hook
    _trace_hook = func
```

GitHub search finds no more references for `_trace_hook`, so presumably that's picked up magically in C code somewhere.

When test() is called, it turns out the sys.settrace() call is made...but then the call to trace_dispatch() does not happen.